# Joint Probability Question

Tags: probability

I have a question regarding join distributions. For this question, I have to find the probability that $P(X+Y=0)$. I've attempted multiple different ways to solve this problem, but I keep getting $0$ as my answer. Could somebody please point me in the right direction on how I can solve this problem?

Below is my joint probability table:

```
                    Y 
        0     1     2     3     4
X   0   0.5   0     0     0     0
    1   0     0     0.05  0.05  0.2
    2   0.1   0.1   0     0     0
```

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are each non-negative, $X+Y=0 \iff X=0 \text{ and } Y=0$

Comment: I understand now! Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: I’m confused by the table.  It looks like you aren’t adding x and y.